# How can I sort a list of numbers using dfs and gbfs (greedy bfs)?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

How can I sort a list of numbers using dfs and gbfs (greedy bfs)?
I need to ordinate the list using an interchange operator between 2 objects from the list.
This is what I have done:

```
class state:
    def __init__(self, l):
      self.listt=l.copy()
    def operator(self, i,j):
      aux=self.listt[j]
      self.listt[j]=self.listt[i]
      self.listt[i]=aux
    def get_children(self):
      rez=[]
      for i in range(self.listt):
          for j in range(i, self.listt):
              if self.listt[i]>self.listt[j]:
                dummy=state(self.listt)
                dummy.operator(i, j)
                rez.append(dummy)
      return rez
```

How can I use now dfs and gbfs to ordinate the list?

Comment: You didn't explain the algorithm you're using to to do what you want. It's difficult to understand the code without any explanation.

Comment: Like what? Your comment is missing something.